# App on appstore has iPad support when iPhone family set?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an app on the App Store and I've made sure several times that iPhone is selected in: App > Target > General > Deployment Info > Devices > iPhone

..rather than Universal or iPad.

It appears every time the app is approved it still says iPad supported, how can I disable iPad support completely since the above "solution" doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making them "Just for iPhone" doesn't let iPads **not** use them. Imagine this bit of a crisis: on the **first** iPad's release, how did apps get on the store, **since they were designed for iPhone?** Developers had some options:

- **Make an "HD" or "iPad" version.** This involved redoing the **entire** UI so it would fit on the bigger screen.
- **Do nothing.** The iPad's would get the iPhone version of the app, but they would just be, as you can guess, oversized iPhone apps.

After a couple years, there was another option:

- **Make a "universal" app.** This allowed **both** UI's, both big and small, retina and 1x scale devices, to be "bundled" together in the same Bundle. (heh, bundle pun.) Puns aside, this allowed for apps like "Facebook" to run on iPad, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6, the future iPhone cheeseburger double-decker 7+, and everything else, without having to remake the **entire app.**

On the iPad, as mentioned by Andrea, it runs in an "iPhone Simulator" mode. This makes the tiny screen be rendered in the tiny screen scale, and, since iPad is over twice the size of the iPhone, it gave the iPad a "2x" button to zoom it in and make the UI bigger.

It's like an app designed for iPhone 4 running on an iPhone 6 Plus.

The iPhone 4 renders stuff at 960x720 landscape or 720x960 portrait, and iPhone 6 Plus's display is much bigger. To accommodate, it letterboxes the content and scales it up automatically.

Answer (score 2):

That is normal, iPhone applications can also run on iPad in a iPhone simulator mode.
This is the description of one application of mine only available for iPhone.

> Compatibility: Requires iOS 7.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone,
>   iPad, and iPod touch. This app is optimized for iPhone 5.

This one just for iPad:

> Compatibility: Requires iOS 7.0 or later. Compatible with iPad.

and this Universal (both iphone and ipad, no simulator)

> Compatibility: Requires iOS 7.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone,
>   iPad, and iPod touch. This app is optimized for iPhone 5.

It seems the same, but in the reality there is also a + sign with written:

> This app is designed for both iPhone and iPad